# jQuery / Javascript loop increment value does not reset with .height compare (part of infinite scrolling script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

Objective is to call an ajax function to populate the screen with data until it reaches the bottom of the screen, then stop.  The script works to populate the screen, but does not stop at the bottom (part of an infinite scrolling script).

The stop mechanism is a compare of window height to position of the last added data.  If the bottom is reached, then  set the "i" to 100, thus ending the loop.

I placed alert code to observe the values and sure enough, I see the #load_data.height point exceeding the window.height (means data loaded is past bottom of screen), but the "i" never gets set to 100 at that point.

I've tried placing the "stopping" code in 3 different places, but none of them seem to take.

Some insight into the problem would help, or suggest an alternative approach to continue ajax data loading until bottom of the screen is reached.   Code below:

```
    var myFunc01 = function(limit,start) {
      var i = 0;
      while (i < 100) {
        (function(i) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            start=start+limit;
            load_data(limit,start);//calls ajax routine to append data to #load_data

                //alert is for checking purposes only to view "if" values
                alert(
                     'window height:'+$(window).height()+'\n'+
                     'load data height:'+$("#load_data").height()+'\n'+
                     'value of i:'+i
                 );

                 if($("#load_data").height() > $(window).height()){i=100;}//this location does not work
          }, 1000 * i)
          if($("#load_data").height() > $(window).height()){i=100;}//this location does not work
        })(i++)
        if($("#load_data").height() > $(window).height()){i=100;}//this location does not work
      }
    };

    myFunc01(limit,start);
```

Comment: whoa. well, uh, first off, the loop is done iterating before any of those lines and alert run. There's a lot wrong here.

Comment: The alert will also happen before your ajax runs, and before the ajax complete inserts html...

Comment: The alert will also alter the outcome of the code vs not having an alert due to the way alerts pause everything.

Comment: So you are saying all 100 iterations are complete before the compare code receives the correct display height data because nothing is displayed yet?  Even though I see the data being loaded every second, it is just the display component taking place after the 100 iterations?  I thought the setTimeout function would have taken care of this issue...obviously not?

Comment: that is correct. the 100 iterations are done almost instantaneously. A while loop cannot be delayed other than through the use of async/await. Looping is probably just the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: Any clues you can give me to have a way to stop the iteration and check before continuing?

Comment: you can't. and due to that, the whole process you're following has to be rearranged.

Comment: OK - good to know this is an impossible situation and I can quit this approach!  Think I will then check screen size and calculate the number of iterations needed to fill to the bottom...think that should work.

Comment: Basically... make a recursive function. It loads data, appends it, checks height, if it's within acceptable range, load more data. Repeat until full

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin B for giving me the hint to use a recursive function...it was so easy after that - one minute and 2 lines of code.  I'll post my solution here in case someone in the future runs into this.

FYI - the more complete routine I have is an infinite/auto scroll, but the problem I had was the initial population of the page was based on a fixed number of data retrievals, say 10. If the end of the data landed on the middle of the page, the routine got stuck and the user would have to shrink the window and scroll past that point to auto load.

Yes, could have retrieved 100 and that would be past the bottom anyways, but that was not the goal here.

The fix is to my ajax function, which once initiated, calls itself until the bottom is reached and quits. The code I added to the bottom of the ajax call was:

```
start = start + limit;
if($("#load_data").height() < $(window).height()){load_data(limit,start);}
```

I noticed many web examples/tutorials of infinite scrolling do not address this issue of getting stuck on initial load if not past the page bottom.

My script below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var limit = 10;//number of records to autoload each time
        var start = 0;//start at record 0
        var action = 'inactive';//initial status to get initial load
        function load_data(limit, start){
            var loads;
            $.ajax({
                 url:"questions_all_autoscroll_fetchdata.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{limit:limit, start:start},
                 cache:false,
                 success:function(data){
                    $('#load_data').append(data);
                    //checks if quantity "limit" amount loaded.  If not, that means end of data reached.
                    //Each data piece has id="container", so counting them tells how many data pieces returned in "loads"
                    loads = $(data).filter('.container').length;
                    if(loads<limit){button_name = 'End of Data';}else{button_name='Please Wait, Loading More...';}
                    //append data returned to bottom of existing data
                    $('#load_data_message').html("<div id='please_wait' class='form-row text-center'>\
                          <div class='col-12'><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>\
                          "+button_name+"</button></div></div>");
                    action = "inactive";
                    //recursive part - keep loading data until bottom of screen reached, stop when reached, or when end of data
                    start = start + limit;
                    if(loads>=limit){
                        if($("#load_data").height() < $(window).height()){load_data(limit,start);}
                    }
                 }
            });            
        }
        //for initial loading of data to the bottom of page (through recursive load_data function
        if(action == 'inactive') {
            action = 'active';
            load_data(limit, start);
         }  
        //autoload portion.  when scrolling reaches bottom of screen, triggers another load of data
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive'){  
                action = 'active';
                start = start + limit;
                setTimeout(function(){
                 load_data(limit, start);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```